# How to use sort function along with $or and $and?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have to get the data from MongoDB, based on some limits and it should be sorted by date and time. I've tried the code below with no luck.

```
    var startDate = new Date();
    var  endDate = new Date();
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 365);
    collections.find({
        $and: [{
            $or: [{
                "times.0.date": {
                    $gte: endDate,
                    $lte: startDate
                }
            }, {
                "times.date": {
                    $gte: endDate,
                    $lte: startDate
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "user_id": parseInt(user._id)
        }],
        $sort: [{startDate: -1}]
    })
```

Comment: What is your result and what did you expect?

Comment: @ThomasSablik it should be sorted by date and time , now am getting output  but not in order

Comment: Did you try `$sort:[{"times.date": -1}]`

Comment: Or `collections.find({...}).sort({ "times.date": -1 })`

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes `collections.find({...}).sort({ "times.date": -1 })` works for me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find your results and then sort them with

```
collections.find({
    $and: [{
        $or: [{
            "times.0.date": {
                $gte: endDate,
                $lte: startDate
            }
        }, {
            "times.date": {
                $gte: endDate,
                $lte: startDate
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "user_id": parseInt(user._id)
    }]
}).sort({ "times.date": -1 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **sort()** method after the **find()** method not inside find method and use 
 `$or, $and` inside find.

```
db.bios.find({$and: [{$or: [{..},{..}]}]}).sort( { name: 1 } )
```